# Is it possible to send markup (inline) keyboard along with the text message with Telegram TDLib via a none-bot account?

Tags: telegram, tdlib

It says in Telegram Core Documentation [here](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1send_message.html):

> Markup for replying to the message; ***for bots only***.

So it seems that inline keyboards with callbacks (reply_markup) are only for bots.like this:

```
$keyboard = [
    ['7', '8', '9'],
    ['4', '5', '6'],
    ['1', '2', '3'],
         ['0']
];

$reply_markup = $telegram->replyKeyboardMarkup([
    'keyboard' => $keyboard, 
    'resize_keyboard' => true, 
    'one_time_keyboard' => true
]);

$response = $telegram->sendMessage([
    'chat_id' => 'CHAT_ID', 
    'text' => 'Hello World', 
    'reply_markup' => $reply_markup
]);
```

But what I need is a keyboard with callback sent from a non-bot account to a two-side chat, not a channel or group. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

### No, only bots can send `reply_markup` messages.

Unfortunately this isn't that well documented, however on the [buttons api](https://core.telegram.org/api/bots/buttons) it says:

> **Bots** can attach a ReplyMarkup constructor to outgoing messages, to attach an inline keyboard or a custom reply keyboard.

For now, there's no way to send 'buttons' as a regular telegram user.

Comment: And this makes sense: who will handle callbacks? Another Telegram client? 99% of users use official ones.

Comment: Another user or user himself could handle callbacks =-=. This feature makes sense for people who develop user-bots and want to have inline-based interface